# How to get the data for selected columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below

```
table1
---------    
x   y  z   total  average
========================
1   2  3 
2   3  4 
3   4  5
```

here i need what ever am selecting columns in front end corresponding columns only
need a total and average
for example if i select x,y,total,average columns in front end
i need a output like below

```
x    y   total  avg
1    2    3     1.5
2    3    5     2.5
3    4    7     3.5
```

here am using refcursor with dynamicsql

```
create or replace function sample_refcursor(i_column in varchar) returns refcursor as

$$
declare
c1 refcursor;
begin

drop   table if exists temp_t;
create  temp table temp_t as select x as A,y as B,z as C,total as tot,avg as average from table1;

open c1 for execute('select ' ||i_column|| ' from temp_t group by ' ||i_column);
return c1;
close c1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try: `SELECT x,y, x+y AS total, (x+y)/2 AS average FROM Table;`

Comment: if i select only two columns based on two column calculate total and average

Comment: @MillaresRoo user does not need z

Comment: I see, sorry. Changed.

Comment: how can i know they pass how many columns in front end application

Comment: OK, I think You was Changed when i was writing

Comment: How are you showing the data to the user? Show your front-end code, please.

Comment: i have to calculate total and avg inside a program based on selected columns

Comment: Which programming language you are using ?

Comment: postgresql 9.1 frontend php

Comment: this is my code 

create or replace function sample_refcursor(i_column in varchar) returns refcursor as

$$
declare
c1 refcursor;
begin

drop   table if exists temp_t;
create  temp table temp_t as select x as A,y as B,z as C,total as tot,avg as average from table1;

open c1 for execute('select ' ||i_column|| ' from temp_t group by ' ||i_column);
return c1;
close c1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x, y, x+y AS tot, (x+y)/2 AS Avg From TableName
```

I as per your second table you are not using z.

Use below code

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=publishing user=www password=foo")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

// Performing SQL query
$query = 'SELECT x, y, x+y AS tot, (x+y)/2 AS Avg From TableName';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```